# Дата смещается на сутки при сохранении

Tags: php, symfony2

Доброго времени суток!
Есть symfony-форма для ввода даты. При обработке в запросе приходит текущая дата.

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->getForm(null);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
}
```

А после handleRequest в форме оказывается вчерашняя дата.
При этом проблема только на проде, на локальном сервере проблемы нет.
Настройки временныйх зон и даты одинаковые на обоих серверах и в обоих копяих проекта.
Похоже на ошибку в конфиге, но не ясно куда капать.

**update 201508171123**

```
private function getForm(Campaign $data = null,$disabled = false)
{
        $begin = new \DateTime( );
        $begin->setTime(0, 0);
        $end = new \DateTime();
        $end->setTime(23, 59);
        return $this->createFormBuilder($data)
                        ->add('begin', 'datetime', array(
                            'label' => 'Старт кампании',
                            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                            'time_widget' => 'choice',
                            'with_minutes' => false,
                            'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                            'input' => 'datetime',
                            'disabled' => $disabled,
                            'data' => $data ? $data->getBegin() : $begin,
                        ))
                        ->add('end', 'datetime', array(
                            'label' => 'Завершение кампании',
                            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
                            'time_widget' => 'choice',
                            'with_minutes' => false,
                            'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
                            'input' => 'datetime',
                            'disabled' => $disabled,
                            'data' => $data ? $data->getEnd() : $end,
                        ));
}
```

Вывод php -i. Не думаю что такая разница может приводит к тому что ошибка показывается именно на сервере, а локально все хорошо.
Локально

```
php -i | grep date
date
date/time support => enabled
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
**date.timezone => no value => no value**
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On
```

На сервере

```
php -i | grep date
date
date/time support => enabled
date.default_latitude => 31.7667 => 31.7667
date.default_longitude => 35.2333 => 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
date.sunset_zenith => 90.583333 => 90.583333
**date.timezone => Europe/Moscow => Europe/Moscow**
opcache.file_update_protection => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_freq => 2 => 2
opcache.revalidate_path => Off => Off
opcache.validate_timestamps => On => On
```

Comment: Что за getForm? Если сдобрить все логгером, в какой момент в логе начнут появляться разные значения?

Comment: getFrom() это говнокод который рожает форму. Сразу после handleRequest даты расходятся. Запихнуть дебагер на прод сервер нет возможности.

Comment: Вы ответили, но ничего не пояснили. Что лежит в getForm? Не надо никуда дебаггер запихивать, надо переписать код с использованием логгера, включить ему уровень debug и выявить точку расхождения.

Comment: @Etki проадейтил вопрос. Точка расхождения как раз в handleRequest. Это уже выяснилось с помощь логера + вардампа реквеста и формы. Или вы предлагаете переписать вендорский код?

Comment: Нет, в вендор лезть не стоит, конечно (хотя можно форкнуть, проапдейтить нужное место и подключить как замену пакета). Расхождения, видимо, все-таки из-за таймзоны, с работы не могу сказать ничего подробнее, но теперь можно на локалке попробовать сделать идентичное окружение.

Answer (score 1):

Сталкивался с таким.

Мозг себе вынес.

На серверах были разные ОСИ.

Как оказалось, таймзона "Europe/Kiev" как-то некорректно обрабатывалась.
На одном из серверов поле формы конвертировалось в Y-m-d 00:00:00, а на другом Y-m-d 23:00:00 вчерашнего дня.

Решил проблему слегка костыльно - во всех php.ini прописал Europe/Helsinki

Comment: Я уже написал? что настройки на обоих серверах совпадают.

Comment: Настройка чего?
Если бы всё совпадало - то и проблемы бы не было.......

Comment: Настройки дат и временных зон на серверах. Конфиги проектов различаются только настройкой доступов.

Comment: В данном случае - все настройки - это абсолютно одинаковые версии операционных систем `uname -a`, + одинаковые версии установленных пакетов (как минимум тех, что отвечают за дату-время)

Comment: пакеты из проекта индентичны. Сервера и php настроены одинаково.

Comment: @zenith, тут речь про другие пакеты. Настроены одинаково - у них до байта совпадает вывод отладочной информации (`php -i` вроде)?

Comment: php здесь ни при чём.

Он НЕ высчитывает дату -- 
это делает операционная система

Comment: @EvgeniyBudanov, *php здесь ни при чём* — вполне может быть «при чём»: конфигурацию часовых поясов интерпретатор php «несёт на борту», и при переводе времени из одной часовой зоны в другую игнорирует информацию от операционной системы. аналогично поступили и разработчики *java*. это из того, что мне известно.

Comment: Проапдейтил вопрос.

Comment: Как я уже писал, даты на проде и локально совпадают. Тайм зоны внутри php интерпретируется как Europe/Moscow